# Outlook client calendar - sync between 2 organizations

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have 2 accounts in 2 organizations and I would like to sync the calendars between the 2 accounts in such a way that if a have a new appointment on calendar X, that appointment will show also in calendar Y; is that possible? If so, does anyone know how, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the Overlay mode via View > Overlay. This feature allows you to place the Calendar “on top of each other” to create an aggregated view which looks like a single Calendar. See the official link below for more details about this feature:

[View multiple calendars at the same time](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-multiple-calendars-at-the-same-time-fffa8783-0556-4ea1-ba62-3ed8a95a903c)